# How to deploy website in IIS with a host name?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I try to host my application in IIS. Below are the steps that I follow:

- Publish the code and place it in a path.
- Open IIS, right click on "sites" and select "Add Website". In that dialog I gave the site name and selected the app pool created for the application.
- I selected the physical path of the published code.
- I left the IP and port in the binding section without changes.
- and, finally, gave the host name as `fus.km.com`.

When I try to browse the application the page is not Loading "Internet Explorer cannot display the Page"

The machine domain is `km.com`

**UPDATE**

I tried to add the host name to the host file and flushed the DNS. The application asked for user credentials (I use windows Authentication in the application).

But it did not login. On repeated tries it throws the error:

```
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I tried with different user to login but I get the same result.

Comment: Well, does fus.km.com resolve to the IP IIS is listening to? IIS wont do the DNS side automagically.

Comment: yes i tried to ping fus.km.com from CMD and it is pinging